Cannot fetch private repository from self-hosted gitlab in dockerfile
I'm trying to build docker containter for go application but faced with the problem. I can't fetch private module that is in my private repo on self-hosted gitlab. So I need to turn on my vpn to log in to gitlab. I tried to add it to GORPIVATE and set gitlab token in build args but it seems to be useless.
It fails with such error
663.4 go: error loading module requirements
------
Dockerfile:19
--------------------
 17 |     COPY go.mod go.sum ./
 18 |     
 19 | >>> RUN go mod tidy

So heres the Dockerfile:
ARG DEPENDENCY_PROXY_IMAGE_PREFIX
FROM ${DEPENDENCY_PROXY_IMAGE_PREFIX}alpine:3.9 AS build
RUN apk add --no-cache gcc g++ make git go

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

ARG ACCESS_AX_USER
ARG ACCESS_AX_TOKEN

ENV GOPRIVATE='gitlab.muxarc.com/*'
ENV GOSUMDB=off

RUN echo -e "machine gitlab.muxarc.com\nlogin ${ACCESS_AX_USER}\npassword ${ACCESS_AX_TOKEN}" > ~/.netrc

COPY go.mod go.sum ./

RUN go mod tidy

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o /bin/main ./cmd/main.go

FROM ${DEPENDENCY_PROXY_IMAGE_PREFIX}alpine:3.9
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates

ADD https://github.com/golang/go/raw/master/lib/time/zoneinfo.zip /zoneinfo.zip
ENV ZONEINFO /zoneinfo.zip

COPY --from=build /bin/main /bin/main

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/main"]

Here's the command how I start container building
docker --build-arg ACCESS_AX_USER=asdfeed --build-arg ACCESS_AX_TOKEN=<here's my token value> -t test . 
So what can be the problem?
